# Gaining an Element from a List of Tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

So I have a list of tuples defined like so:

```
type Domino = (Int,Int)
data End =  L|R  
type Board = [Domino]
d :: Domino
d= (4,5)
b :: Board
b= [(1,3),(3,3),(3,4)]
```

In my function I need to be able to gain the first part of the board. So for example I can head the board to get the domino (1,3) as a tuple but I've been trying to get the integer one from this and simply failing. I need to be able to compare that integer value. My question is simply how do you acquire the first part of a tuple in an a list as everything I have done and searched keeps failing. Apologies if this is really simple, I am new to haskell. This is my function code, obviously with a bunch of errors

```
goesP :: Domino->Board->End-> Bool
goesP _ []_ = True
goesP dom bor L = (if head bor fst  == fst dom then True else if last bor == snd then True else False)
```

Comment: Somehow. it's not completely clear what you want to do. The first part of a pair can be extracted with `fst :: (a,b) -> a`. Comparing shouldn't be hard.

Comment: `fst (1,3)` yields `1`. Use `snd` for the other component. Alternatively, `case (1,3) of (x,y) -> useBoth x y`. Everything else being equal, I would recommend pattern matching before projections `fst/snd`, and it often leads to clearer code.

Comment: My problem relies in that I need get the tuple from the Board list and then extract the individual element from it. So essentially I have to head the list to return the tuple (1,3) and then fst it to get 1 but I'm trying to do this all in one "section" if that makes sense. I will edit the above with the code for my function

Comment: @cjbatin: You mean like `fst . head`?

Comment: Possibly? I am really new to Haskell and don't understand much of it. If I did that on Board would it return the Integer 1? Tried it and got a type error?

Comment: You can remove this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it doesn't look like you're interested in a generalised function, so these will work:

`fst $ head b` will get the very first `Int` in that list, and `snd $ last b` will get the very last.

How you compare them then is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as

```
goesP :: Domino -> Board -> End -> Bool
goesP _ [] _ = True
goesP _ ((a,b):doms) _ = a
```

will work, as you can pattern match for the list being empty, and then being a pair cons the rest of a list, and extract the first element out of that pair.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the End type in there as well, but I left it in there in my example (although I do nothing with it).

Answer (score 0):

As you may or may not know fst and snd only work for 2-element tuples so for you it should be enough:

```
fst (a,b) = a
```

You can also write you own:

```
get3th (_,_,a,_,_,_,_,_,_,_) = a
```

As you can see you may want to define your own type.